# Как задать угол поворота шарика?

Tags: python, анимация, разработка-игр, pygame, вектор

Всем привет! Недавно открыл для себя pygame и решил сделать простенький пинг-понг с несколькими режимами.
Возникает вопрос, как в начале игры сделать так, чтобы шарик двигался по рандомному вектору? Пробовал с randint, но возникали проблемы со скоростью, то она больше, то меньше, да и бывали случаи, например когда скорость по х или у была нулевой, т.е. шарик двигался исключительно по горизонтали или вертикали(отбивание его ракетками бессильно, т.к. при коллизии просто инвертировалась скорость). Есть ли вариант решения этой проблемы, чтобы при этом шарик двигался с определенной скоростью? В интернете ничего не нашел. Ниже краткая вырезка из кода, описывающая работу программы. Программист из меня фиговый, поэтому прошу, не бейте палками

```
from pygame import*
import play
import random
display_x = 2000
display_y = 900
window = display.set_mode((display_x, display_y))
display.set_caption("Ping-Pong")
run = True
class Rackets(sprite.Sprite):
    border = 5
    height = 200
    width = 20
    posX = border * 12
    posY = display_y - (height*3)
    speed = 5
    def move(self):
        global run
        keys = key.get_pressed()
        if keys[K_w] and self.posY != self.border:
            self.posY -= self.speed
        elif keys[K_s] and self.posY != display_y - self.height - self.border:
            self.posY += self.speed
    def clear(self):
        self.posY = display_y - self.height * 3
    def draw(self):
        self.rackets = Rect(self.posX, self.posY, self.width, self.height)
        draw.rect(window, (255,255,255), self.rackets)   

# создаем класс-наследник с ИИ
class RacketAI(Rackets):
    border = 5
    speed = 4.0
    posX = display_x - border * 12
    def move(self, bX, bY, display_x, display_y):
        if (self.posY + self.height / 2) < bY and self.posY < (display_y - self.height - self.border):
            self.posY += self.speed
        elif (self.posY + self.height / 2) > bY and self.posY > self.border:
            self.posY -= self.speed
    def clear(self):
        self.posY = display_y - self.height * 3
    def draw(self):
        self.rackets = Rect(self.posX, self.posY, self.width, self.height)
        draw.rect(window, (255, 255, 255), self.rackets)

# создаем мяч
class Ball(sprite.Sprite):
    width = 30
    posX = display_x / 2
    posY = display_y / 2
    border = 5
    speedX = random.randint(-5, 5)
    speedY = random.randint(-5, 5)
    speed = -1
    def move(self, r1X, r2X, r1, r2):
        global run
        self.posX += self.speedX
        self.posY += self.speedY
        b = Rect(self.posX - self.width / 2, self.posY - self.width / 2, self.width, self.width)
        if self.posY >= (display_y - self.width / 2 - self.border):                                         
            self.speedY *= self.speed
        elif self.posY <= self.border:
            self.speedY *= self.speed
        elif (b.colliderect(r1) and self.posX >= r1X + 10) or (b.colliderect(r2) and self.posX <= r2X - 10):                                              
            self.speedX *= self.speed
        else:
            if self.posX < r1X:
                run = False
            elif self.posX > r2X:
                run = False
    def clear(self):
        self.posX = display_x / 2
        self.posY = display_y / 2
        self.speedX = random.randint(-2, 2)
        self.speedY = random.randint(-2, 2)
    def draw(self):
        b = Rect(self.posX - self.width / 2, self.posY - self.width / 2, self.width, self.width)
        draw.ellipse(window, (255, 255, 255), b)

def draw_line():
    draw.line(window, (255, 255, 255), (display_x / 2, 0), (display_x / 2, display_y), 4)
ball = Ball()
racket1 = Rackets()
racketAI = RacketAI()
clock = time.Clock()
while run:
    window.fill((0,0,0))
    draw_line()
    racket1.move()
    racket1.draw()
    racketAI.move(ball.posX, ball.posY, display_x, display_y)
    racketAI.draw()
    ball.draw()  
    ball.move(racket1.posX, racketAI.posX, racket1.rackets, racketAI.rackets)                                                                                                                               
    clock.tick(120)
    display.update()
    for e in event.get():
        if e.type == QUIT:
            run = False
```

Answer (score 3):

Вот код, генерирующий два компонента вектора случайного направления с длиной (скоростью), равной velocity

```
import random, math

velocity = 10
angle = random.random() * 2 * math.pi
speedX = velocity * math.cos(angle)
speedY = velocity * math.sin(angle)
print(speedX, speedY)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: спасибо большое, но можно чуток попроще?;) я просто в 7 классе

Comment: Я добавил рабочий Python код. Что именно вызывает затруднения, если понятие вектора знакомо?

Comment: или распишите пожалуйста чуть подробнее

Comment: Вы обновили эту страницу?